# Correct sentence construction Using need and needs

Tags: sentence-construction

Which Sentence construction is correct?

a) This Excel Column *needs* to be at the end of the Report..

Or

b) This Excel Column *need* to be at the end of the Report.

Is it like meaning of both the sentences is same?

Comment: First of all, you need to tell us what your thoughts on that are.

Comment: I think Second one is correct as sentence doesn't have Subject so first for of verb is correct.

Comment: Only sentence *a)* is correct because the subject, *this Excel column*, is singular and in English singular subjects are only used with singular verbs. That's where *needs* comes in since it's the third-person singular form of the verb *to need*. So, that's why it should be *this Excel column needs*. Is my explanation clear enough?

Comment: Should I Say "To cleared this it need to be explained" or "To cleared this it needs to be explained" ;-)

Comment: If you have another question, please create a new post and explain what exactly you have a problem with.

Comment: Can Need is use as Model verb can and Needs use as requires ?

Comment: When users request more details from you, please use the **[edit]** button to include that information **in** the post. Otherwise, your question may be closed because it lacks improvements.

Answer (score 1):

***Is "this excel column" singular or plural?***

It's singular, because "this" is singular. Thus, you use the verb that pairs with singular subjects, which is "needs".

A rule that is sometimes taught when learning English is that if the noun doesn't end in "s" (so it's a singular noun), then you add an "s" to the verb. Of course, there are many exceptions to this rule. All of this to say...

The correct answer is:

> This excel column needs to be at the end of the report.

Note the capitalization in the sentence. You could capitalize Excel if you really wanted to, as it is technically a proper noun (the name of a product), but no one really does that. The name of your report isn't "Report" (I'm assuming), so it doesn't have to be capitalized.